# SharePoint designer workflow, special task action, I dont receive emails after assigned task

Tags: workflow

I am using SharePoint 2013. I created a SharePoint Designer workflow. I created an advanced task action. I assign this task to a SharePoint group. In this group I have 2 users. These 2 users dont get an email after the task is created and assigned to them. Why?

[image]

Comment: I fixed this. In the advanced settings of this task you can enable notification.

Answer (score 0):

Off to the right of "starten" you should be able to toggle a drop down. Choose properties and make sure that "SendDefaultTaskNotifications" is set to yes. Hope thats it!

Edit: Sorry saw your comment afterwards, nice work!